Setup Playstore on CI using Github Actions for Appium testing
Context: I am working on creating automation tests for our Android app using Appium. The setup is working fine but for few tests I need to signin to Google Playstore which I can't figure out how to do.
Problem There are few tests like testing purchase flows which uses Google purchase that needs Google Play service to be active and for that I need to login into the playstore which I am not sure how I can do it on emulator on CI as I create a new emulator each time I run the test suite.
I saw this thread as well https://discuss.appium.io/t/sign-in-to-google-account-with-appium/33763 but i can't use browser stack but someone mentioned that browser stack is using some public APIs to do so, not sure which are those exactly
Any help or guidance would be really appreciated in how I can setup the playstore.
